# Why can't I resize a partition?

Tags: partitioning, resize

I know there are many questions about this, but none of them worked out for me. 
[image: So, my partitions look like this]

I need to enlarge /home with the space of the "sin asignar" partition.

Everyone says i just got to press "Resize/move" and then move it, well, this is what I see...

[image]

Can anyone give me some advice? By the way, the screenshots are taken from my OS, but I always try to do it from a Gparted Live USB.

Comment: Because the free space is not next to your /home partition.  You will need to move around the other partitions to get the free space to follow the /home partition in order to grow it.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** This is happening because your /home partition is between other two non-empty ones.

---

## Explanation

Think of the hard drive as a line of people (each person is a partition).

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
```

If number 3 leaves the line, a free space appears. That would be your unassigned space:

```
| 1 | 2 |   | 4 | 5 | 6 |
```

If number 5 wants to have 2 spaces instead of one, it can't, because it's trapped between 4 and 6!
So, it has to kindly ask number 4 to move next to 2, so the line looks like this:

```
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 ¦ 5 | 6 |
```

---

## How to solve it

> **WARNING:** This procedure goes wrong more often than you think, so if you want to avoid losing all your data, make a backup. Seriously. Do it.

So, in your case, you should follow these steps if you want to enlarge your /home partition:

1. Move /sda3 to the left, by right-clicking on it and choosing *"Resize/move"*. This will probably take long.
2. Enlarge /sda4 with the empty space on its left.
3. Move /sda6 to the left with the same procedure as before. This will take even longer.
4. Finally, enlarge /home as much as you want.

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot about this! Hewbot answer totally worked, thank you so much!!!